# Dynamic store model grid columns

Tags: extjs

The grid looks to have the right number of rows displayed and the column headers are correct but the actual data in the cells is blank. Any idea why this is happening?

data

```
var data = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<sio><sql><row><Name>item 1</Name><Dn>value 1</Dn></row><row><Name>item 2</Name><Dn>value 2</Dn></row></sql></sio>',"text/xml");
var columns=JSON.parse('[{"dataIndex": "Name","text": "NEW Clumn Name"},{"dataIndex": "Dn","text": "NEW Column Dn"}]');
var fields = JSON.parse('[{"name": "Name","type": "string"},{"name": "Dn","type": "string"}]');
```

model

```
var model = new Ext.data.Model({
    fields: fields
});
```

new model

```
Ext.define('testModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: [
        'Ext.data.field.String',
    ],
    fields: fields
});
```

store

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    // model: model, // this not works
    model: 'testModel', // this works
    // fields: fields, // this works
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            rootProperty: 'sql',
            record: 'row'
        }
    }
});
```

grid

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    title: 'Test',
                    titleAlign: 'center',
                    columnLines: true,
                    id: 'testGrid',
                    forceFit: true,
                    store: store,
                });
```

load

```
grid.reconfigure(store,columns);
store.loadRawData(data);
console.log(fields);
```

log **$reference: undefined** - any idea what that means

```
[Object, Object]
  0: Object
    $reference: undefined
    name: "Name"
    type: "string"
```

Comment: in the model definition, you seem to want to use the variable `fields` but there's a typo, you assign `field` (undefined) to the fields property of the model.

Comment: What ExtJS version do you use? It looks like ExtJS 3, isn't it?

Comment: **field** is a syntax error of example - should be **fields**.
Ext JS 5.1.x

Comment: Would suggest you look at the example. The `model` store config is meant to be a model type, not an instance of some model.